Disable markdown interpretation within print variable in Jekyll
I'm outputting some data in one of my jekyll templates, like so:
{{ post.content }}
The problem is if there is any markdown like data inside content, jekyll will automatically parse the markdown and output HTML tags etc within the content, completely breaking my page layout.
Is there a filter or something I can use to instruct jekyll not to parse the markdown within that variable?

I was using markdown="1" in my wrapping html element so that I could use markdown for my template inside the div. This apparently instructs the interpreter to parse variables for markdown as well. To get around in, I enclosed the output line in a p tag like so <p>{{ post.content }}</p> and it stopped parsing the markdown inside the variable
